# Django 'pip install django-heroku'(psycopg2) error is blocking deployment to Heroku

Tags: django, python-3.x, heroku, pip, psycopg2

I am setting up a new Django project to deploy on Heroku, however when I am following the Django Heroku deployment guide I come across an error during 'pip install django-heroku'.

I am running on: 
OS: `MacOS Mojave 10.14.6`
virtualenv: python3
pip freeze output:

```
(env) MacBook-Pro:testing_django sudoxx2$ pip freeze
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==2.2.3
gunicorn==19.9.0
psycopg2-binary==2.8.3
pytz==2019.1
sqlparse==0.3.0
whitenoise==4.1.3
```

Here is the error output after executing the `pip install django-heroku` command:

```
(env) MacBook-Pro:testing_django sudoxx2$ pip install psycopg2-binary
Collecting psycopg2-binary
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ee/ed/2772267467ba5c21a73d37149da0b49a4343c6646d501dbb1450b492d40a/psycopg2_binary-2.8.3-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl
Installing collected packages: psycopg2-binary
Successfully installed psycopg2-binary-2.8.3
(env) MacBook-Pro:testing_django sudoxx2$ pip install django-heroku
Collecting django-heroku
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/59/af/5475a876c5addd5a3494db47d9f7be93cc14d3a7603542b194572791b6c6/django_heroku-0.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting psycopg2 (from django-heroku)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5c/1c/6997288da181277a0c29bc39a5f9143ff20b8c99f2a7d059cfb55163e165/psycopg2-2.8.3.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: whitenoise in /Users/sudoxx2/Documents/github/delete_copy/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from django-heroku) (4.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: django in /Users/sudoxx2/Documents/github/delete_copy/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from django-heroku) (2.2.3)
Requirement already satisfied: dj-database-url>=0.5.0 in /Users/sudoxx2/Documents/github/delete_copy/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from django-heroku) (0.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: sqlparse in /Users/sudoxx2/Documents/github/delete_copy/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from django->django-heroku) (0.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in /Users/sudoxx2/Documents/github/delete_copy/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from django->django-heroku) (2019.1)
Installing collected packages: psycopg2, django-heroku
  Running setup.py install for psycopg2 ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/sudoxx2/Documents/github/delete_copy/env/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/4d/s84v7k6d1dx_m_6qbd1wfbz80000gp/T/pip-install-cq6yuehb/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/4d/s84v7k6d1dx_m_6qbd1wfbz80000gp/T/pip-install-cq6yuehb/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/4d/s84v7k6d1dx_m_6qbd1wfbz80000gp/T/pip-record-tyidyv7j/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/sudoxx2/Documents/github/delete_copy/env/include/site/python3.7/psycopg2
         cwd: /private/var/folders/4d/s84v7k6d1dx_m_6qbd1wfbz80000gp/T/pip-install-cq6yuehb/psycopg2/
    Complete output (48 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/_json.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/extras.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/errorcodes.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/tz.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/_range.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/_ipaddress.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/_lru_cache.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/extensions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/errors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/sql.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/pool.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    running build_ext
    building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=110004 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/sudoxx2/Documents/github/delete_copy/env/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.4/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.4/include/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o
    In file included from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:27:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:34:
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/Python.h:30:10: warning: non-portable path to file '<String.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
    #include <string.h>
             ^~~~~~~~~~
             <String.h>
    In file included from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:27:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:34:
    In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/Python.h:30:
    /usr/local/include/string.h:25:10: fatal error: 'plist/Node.h' file not found
    #include <plist/Node.h>
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 warning and 1 error generated.

    It appears you are missing some prerequisite to build the package from source.

    You may install a binary package by installing 'psycopg2-binary' from PyPI.
    If you want to install psycopg2 from source, please install the packages
    required for the build and try again.

    For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
    <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html>).

    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/sudoxx2/Documents/github/delete_copy/env/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/4d/s84v7k6d1dx_m_6qbd1wfbz80000gp/T/pip-install-cq6yuehb/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/4d/s84v7k6d1dx_m_6qbd1wfbz80000gp/T/pip-install-cq6yuehb/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/4d/s84v7k6d1dx_m_6qbd1wfbz80000gp/T/pip-record-tyidyv7j/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/sudoxx2/Documents/github/delete_copy/env/include/site/python3.7/psycopg2 Check the logs for full command output.
(env) MacBook-Pro:testing_django sudoxx2$ pip install psycopg2-binary
Collecting psycopg2-binary
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ee/ed/2772267467ba5c21a73d37149da0b49a4343c6646d501dbb1450b492d40a/psycopg2_binary-2.8.3-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl
Installing collected packages: psycopg2-binary
Successfully installed psycopg2-binary-2.8.3
(env) MacBook-Pro:testing_django sudoxx2$ pip install django-heroku
Collecting django-heroku
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/59/af/5475a876c5addd5a3494db47d9f7be93cc14d3a7603542b194572791b6c6/django_heroku-0.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting psycopg2 (from django-heroku)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5c/1c/6997288da181277a0c29bc39a5f9143ff20b8c99f2a7d059cfb55163e165/psycopg2-2.8.3.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: whitenoise in /Users/sudoxx2/Documents/github/delete_copy/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from django-heroku) (4.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: django in /Users/sudoxx2/Documents/github/delete_copy/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from django-heroku) (2.2.3)
Requirement already satisfied: dj-database-url>=0.5.0 in /Users/sudoxx2/Documents/github/delete_copy/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from django-heroku) (0.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: sqlparse in /Users/sudoxx2/Documents/github/delete_copy/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from django->django-heroku) (0.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in /Users/sudoxx2/Documents/github/delete_copy/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from django->django-heroku) (2019.1)
Installing collected packages: psycopg2, django-heroku
  Running setup.py install for psycopg2 ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/sudoxx2/Documents/github/delete_copy/env/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/4d/s84v7k6d1dx_m_6qbd1wfbz80000gp/T/pip-install-cq6yuehb/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/4d/s84v7k6d1dx_m_6qbd1wfbz80000gp/T/pip-install-cq6yuehb/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/4d/s84v7k6d1dx_m_6qbd1wfbz80000gp/T/pip-record-tyidyv7j/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/sudoxx2/Documents/github/delete_copy/env/include/site/python3.7/psycopg2
         cwd: /private/var/folders/4d/s84v7k6d1dx_m_6qbd1wfbz80000gp/T/pip-install-cq6yuehb/psycopg2/
    Complete output (48 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/_json.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/extras.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/errorcodes.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/tz.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/_range.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/_ipaddress.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/_lru_cache.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/extensions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/errors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/sql.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/pool.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    running build_ext
    building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=110004 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/sudoxx2/Documents/github/delete_copy/env/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.4/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.4/include/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o
    In file included from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:27:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:34:
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/Python.h:30:10: warning: non-portable path to file '<String.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
    #include <string.h>
             ^~~~~~~~~~
             <String.h>
    In file included from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:27:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:34:
    In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/Python.h:30:
    /usr/local/include/string.h:25:10: fatal error: 'plist/Node.h' file not found
    #include <plist/Node.h>
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 warning and 1 error generated.

    It appears you are missing some prerequisite to build the package from source.

    You may install a binary package by installing 'psycopg2-binary' from PyPI.
    If you want to install psycopg2 from source, please install the packages
    required for the build and try again.

    For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
    <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html>).

    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/sudoxx2/Documents/github/delete_copy/env/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/4d/s84v7k6d1dx_m_6qbd1wfbz80000gp/T/pip-install-cq6yuehb/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/4d/s84v7k6d1dx_m_6qbd1wfbz80000gp/T/pip-install-cq6yuehb/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/4d/s84v7k6d1dx_m_6qbd1wfbz80000gp/T/pip-record-tyidyv7j/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/sudoxx2/Documents/github/delete_copy/env/include/site/python3.7/psycopg2 Check the logs for full command output.(env) MacBook-Pro:testing_django sudoxx2$ pip install psycopg2-binary
Collecting psycopg2-binary
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ee/ed/2772267467ba5c21a73d37149da0b49a4343c6646d501dbb1450b492d40a/psycopg2_binary-2.8.3-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl
Installing collected packages: psycopg2-binary
Successfully installed psycopg2-binary-2.8.3
(env) MacBook-Pro:testing_django sudoxx2$ pip install django-heroku
Collecting django-heroku
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/59/af/5475a876c5addd5a3494db47d9f7be93cc14d3a7603542b194572791b6c6/django_heroku-0.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting psycopg2 (from django-heroku)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5c/1c/6997288da181277a0c29bc39a5f9143ff20b8c99f2a7d059cfb55163e165/psycopg2-2.8.3.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: whitenoise in /Users/sudoxx2/Documents/github/delete_copy/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from django-heroku) (4.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: django in /Users/sudoxx2/Documents/github/delete_copy/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from django-heroku) (2.2.3)
Requirement already satisfied: dj-database-url>=0.5.0 in /Users/sudoxx2/Documents/github/delete_copy/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from django-heroku) (0.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: sqlparse in /Users/sudoxx2/Documents/github/delete_copy/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from django->django-heroku) (0.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in /Users/sudoxx2/Documents/github/delete_copy/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from django->django-heroku) (2019.1)
Installing collected packages: psycopg2, django-heroku
  Running setup.py install for psycopg2 ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/sudoxx2/Documents/github/delete_copy/env/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/4d/s84v7k6d1dx_m_6qbd1wfbz80000gp/T/pip-install-cq6yuehb/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/4d/s84v7k6d1dx_m_6qbd1wfbz80000gp/T/pip-install-cq6yuehb/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/4d/s84v7k6d1dx_m_6qbd1wfbz80000gp/T/pip-record-tyidyv7j/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/sudoxx2/Documents/github/delete_copy/env/include/site/python3.7/psycopg2
         cwd: /private/var/folders/4d/s84v7k6d1dx_m_6qbd1wfbz80000gp/T/pip-install-cq6yuehb/psycopg2/
    Complete output (48 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/_json.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/extras.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/errorcodes.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/tz.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/_range.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/_ipaddress.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/_lru_cache.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/extensions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/errors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/sql.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/pool.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    running build_ext
    building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=110004 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/sudoxx2/Documents/github/delete_copy/env/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.4/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.4/include/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o
    In file included from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:27:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:34:
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/Python.h:30:10: warning: non-portable path to file '<String.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
    #include <string.h>
             ^~~~~~~~~~
             <String.h>
    In file included from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:27:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:34:
    In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/Python.h:30:
    /usr/local/include/string.h:25:10: fatal error: 'plist/Node.h' file not found
    #include <plist/Node.h>
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 warning and 1 error generated.

    It appears you are missing some prerequisite to build the package from source.

    You may install a binary package by installing 'psycopg2-binary' from PyPI.
    If you want to install psycopg2 from source, please install the packages
    required for the build and try again.

    For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
    <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html>).

    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/sudoxx2/Documents/github/delete_copy/env/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/4d/s84v7k6d1dx_m_6qbd1wfbz80000gp/T/pip-install-cq6yuehb/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/4d/s84v7k6d1dx_m_6qbd1wfbz80000gp/T/pip-install-cq6yuehb/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/4d/s84v7k6d1dx_m_6qbd1wfbz80000gp/T/pip-record-tyidyv7j/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/sudoxx2/Documents/github/delete_copy/env/include/site/python3.7/psycopg2 Check the logs for full command output.(env) MacBook-Pro:testing_django sudoxx2$ pip install psycopg2-binary
Collecting psycopg2-binary
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ee/ed/2772267467ba5c21a73d37149da0b49a4343c6646d501dbb1450b492d40a/psycopg2_binary-2.8.3-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl
Installing collected packages: psycopg2-binary
Successfully installed psycopg2-binary-2.8.3
(env) MacBook-Pro:testing_django sudoxx2$ pip install django-heroku
Collecting django-heroku
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/59/af/5475a876c5addd5a3494db47d9f7be93cc14d3a7603542b194572791b6c6/django_heroku-0.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting psycopg2 (from django-heroku)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5c/1c/6997288da181277a0c29bc39a5f9143ff20b8c99f2a7d059cfb55163e165/psycopg2-2.8.3.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: whitenoise in /Users/sudoxx2/Documents/github/delete_copy/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from django-heroku) (4.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: django in /Users/sudoxx2/Documents/github/delete_copy/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from django-heroku) (2.2.3)
Requirement already satisfied: dj-database-url>=0.5.0 in /Users/sudoxx2/Documents/github/delete_copy/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from django-heroku) (0.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: sqlparse in /Users/sudoxx2/Documents/github/delete_copy/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from django->django-heroku) (0.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in /Users/sudoxx2/Documents/github/delete_copy/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from django->django-heroku) (2019.1)
Installing collected packages: psycopg2, django-heroku
  Running setup.py install for psycopg2 ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/sudoxx2/Documents/github/delete_copy/env/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/4d/s84v7k6d1dx_m_6qbd1wfbz80000gp/T/pip-install-cq6yuehb/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/4d/s84v7k6d1dx_m_6qbd1wfbz80000gp/T/pip-install-cq6yuehb/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/4d/s84v7k6d1dx_m_6qbd1wfbz80000gp/T/pip-record-tyidyv7j/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/sudoxx2/Documents/github/delete_copy/env/include/site/python3.7/psycopg2
         cwd: /private/var/folders/4d/s84v7k6d1dx_m_6qbd1wfbz80000gp/T/pip-install-cq6yuehb/psycopg2/
    Complete output (48 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/_json.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/extras.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/errorcodes.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/tz.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/_range.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/_ipaddress.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/_lru_cache.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/extensions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/errors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/sql.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/pool.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    running build_ext
    building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=110004 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/sudoxx2/Documents/github/delete_copy/env/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.4/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.4/include/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o
    In file included from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:27:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:34:
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/Python.h:30:10: warning: non-portable path to file '<String.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
    #include <string.h>
             ^~~~~~~~~~
             <String.h>
    In file included from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:27:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:34:
    In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/Python.h:30:
    /usr/local/include/string.h:25:10: fatal error: 'plist/Node.h' file not found
    #include <plist/Node.h>
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 warning and 1 error generated.

    It appears you are missing some prerequisite to build the package from source.

    You may install a binary package by installing 'psycopg2-binary' from PyPI.
    If you want to install psycopg2 from source, please install the packages
    required for the build and try again.

    For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
    <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html>).

    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/sudoxx2/Documents/github/delete_copy/env/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/4d/s84v7k6d1dx_m_6qbd1wfbz80000gp/T/pip-install-cq6yuehb/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/4d/s84v7k6d1dx_m_6qbd1wfbz80000gp/T/pip-install-cq6yuehb/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/4d/s84v7k6d1dx_m_6qbd1wfbz80000gp/T/pip-record-tyidyv7j/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/sudoxx2/Documents/github/delete_copy/env/include/site/python3.7/psycopg2 Check the logs for full command output.
```

I have tried `pip install psycopg2-binary` but no luck.

Made a new project to test and have same error.

Any help would be awesome.

---

### UPDATE 7/31/2019

I tested on windows 10 and everything pass with flying colors and was able to deploy to heroku. It seems like this might be Mojave OS specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested the same steps on windows 10 and everything pass with flying colors and I was able to deploy to heroku.

It seems like this might be MAC OS Mojave specific.

`MacOS Mojave 10.14.6` was the version I had an issue with

Solution for me was to deploy through windows 10 or downgrade to a older Mac OS such as High Sierra.

Answer (score 42):

I have tried several solutions, none worked except simplest solution:

`pip3 install psycopg2==2.7.5`

this command worked perfectly (seems like a problem with a version)

Answer (score 32):

To install heroku in django the command line `django-heroku` changed to

```
pip install django-on-heroku
```

Comment: To anyone stuck and failing with the other ones: THIS IS THE MOST ACCURATE ANSWER AND WILL SOLVE YOUR PROBLEM ALMOST IMMEDIATELY.

Answer (score 13):

**For MacOS users**

After trying all the above methods (which did not work for me on MacOS 10.14), that one worked :

Install openssl with

```
brew install openssl
```

if you don't have it already.
add openssl path to LIBRARY_PATH :

```
export LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/
```

install psycopg2 with pip

```
pip3 install psycopg2
```

I was searching and this finally worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

do this and it will work

1. `brew install postgresql`
2. `pip3 install psycopg2`
3. `pip install django-heroku`

Answer (score 4):

I have had the same issue and kept wondering why Heroku had not updated the package `django-heroku` package to fix this. However we should not expect updates to fix this. The django-heroku repo has been achieved on github. `https://github.com/heroku/django-heroku`.
Closer look at `https://github.com/heroku/django-heroku/blob/master/setup.py` will show you they listed `psycopg2` as a requirement. Hence why it tries to install on your computer. 
Solution to this.

```
 1. Remove django-heroku package from your requirements.
 2. Remove django-heroku settings from settings.py
 3. Set STATIC_ROOT.
 4. Add your heroku url to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
```

`Django-heroku` is no longer needed to host Django applications on heroku. I have tested the above with an application running on DJango 2.2.

Answer (score 3):

Recently ran into the issue . 
What helped me is pip3 install psycopg2==2.8.3 and later on pip3 install django-heroku

Answer (score 2):

From [docs](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html)
For most operating systems, the quickest way to install Psycopg is using the wheel package available on PyPI:

```
$ pip install psycopg2-binary
```

This will install a pre-compiled binary version of the module which does not require the build or runtime prerequisites.

you should get such a response

```
Collecting psycopg2-binary
  Downloading psycopg2_binary-2.8.6-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (3.0 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 3.0 MB 62 kB/s 
Installing collected packages: psycopg2-binary
Successfully installed psycopg2-binary-2.8.6
```

Answer (score 1):

OS: `MacOS Mojave 10.14.4`

virtualenv: `python3.6`

I'm not using heroku but was getting the same error and this is what fixed it for me:

```
sudo installer -pkg /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg -target /
```

after that you should be able to install via pip:

```
(venv) MacBook-Pro:testing_django user$ pip install psycopg2
```

```
(venv) MacBook-Pro:testing_django user$ pip freeze
Django==2.2.4
psycopg2==2.8.3
pytz==2019.2
sqlparse==0.3.0
```

from: https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/3438#issuecomment-435169249

Comment: Hi I ran your command and didn't work for me. Still getting same error

Comment: Not sure if you did this yet, but the command mentioned above is a follow-up suggestion after having already installed Xcode command line tools: `xcode-select --install` Aside from that, I would note the differences in our setup: you're using `psycopg2-binary` and `python 3.7.x`, whereas I am using `psycopg2` and `python 3.6.9`. I am also not using heroku and do not have experience with it. My last suggestion would be to install postgresql via homebrew: `brew install postgresql`. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue for a while then this helped me:

```
brew install openssl
```

Add `openssl` path to `LIBRARY_PATH`:

```
export LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/
```

Install `psycopg2` with pip:

```
pip3 install psycopg2
```

then finally:

```
pip3 install django-heroku
```

Answer (score 1):

In linux,try

> sudo apt install libpq-dev

> pip install django-heroku

I solved my issue using these commands

if it is not working,try

> sudo apt install django-on-heroku

Answer (score 1):

`pip install django-on-heroku` changed psycopg2 to psycopg2-binary so it works and is installable!

Comment: https://github.com/pkrefta/django-on-heroku

Comment: Instead of [repeating the same answer already posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61941034/6243352), consider _upvoting_ that answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install **postgres db**, **postgres client** and **libpq-dev** via os commands
Then you can install below in python environ

```
pip install psycopg2
```

For more details look at http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html

Comment: Not working for me after installing those 3 suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Update: Oct.12.2021

Same solution as @Artur offered but I had to change the version to

```
pip3 install psycopg2==2.9
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this brew install postgresql to install packages with the correct wheel file. When a venv is activated, sometimes you need to download the correct wheel file to install certain packages. This installation uses setup.py install instead making it easy for the virtual environment to install the desired package using the pip3 installation. Another common package that requires this installation is scikit-learn.

```
brew install postgresql
pip3 install psycopg2
pip3 install django-heroku
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was missing `sudo apt-get install python3-dev`. I already had psycopg2-2.9.3 but this then enabled `pip install django-heroku` to compile correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
pip install django-on-heroku
```

**Why?**

`psycopg2` requires the `Postgres` utility file, named `pg_config`. The `pg_config` utility prints configuration parameters of the currently installed version of PostgreSQL. If it is missing since you don't like to install `Postgres` locally, the solution is using `psycopg2-binary`. The `django-heroku` module requires `psycopg2` and has been archived and no maintenance is available for it. A forked, [`django-on-heroku`](http://pypi.org/project/django-on-heroku/), has been created which uses `psycopg2-binary`.